# React js web page to React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to convert my current react js website into a react native app? any ideas on how to achieve this task? or do I have to code react native? do you know a component or a way to do that ?

Comment: You can google about it, there are articles about this subject. There is no automatic way to do this, so my recommendation would just be to read what parts of the code you can (and should) keep and which parts you cannot, and start working with that. We have made this move in our company quite easily.

Comment: You will have to use react-native components (and none from DOM will work), so you would have to modify the JSX parts of your code. However, all the life cycle logic should be able to remain exactly the same.

Comment: thanks guys for your suggestions